# I'm getting errors in this program for armstrong number

Tags: command-line, bash

```
echo "Enter the no"
read a
echo "The number is:"
echo $a
b=  `expr $a % 10`
c= `expr $a / 10`
d= `expr $c % 10`
e= `expr $d / 10`
f= `expr $b \* $b \* $b + $d \* $d \* $d + $e \* $e \* $e`
if [ $f -eq $a ];then
echo "Armstrong No."
else
echo "Not an Armstrong No"
fi
```

the errors displayed are:

```
PS:Input no. is 153
Armstrong.sh: line 5: 3: command not found
Armstrong.sh: line 6: 15: command not found
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
expr: non-numeric argument
Armstrong.sh: line 10: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Answer (score 1):

While declaring variables in shell, there **must** not be any whitespace(s) around `=`.

In your case, let's take one line for example: `` b=  `expr $a % 10` ``, you are trying to save the output of command substitution `` `expr $a % 10` `` in variable `b`; as there is a space after `b=`, you are gettimng the error. This is true for all the later cases too. So, drop the space(s) after `b=`.

As a side note, start using the command substitution syntax `$()` instead of older and deprecated `` ` ` `` to avoid problems like nesting command substitution and weird quoting issues:

```
b=$(expr $a % 10)
```

Also, you should quote your variable expansions unless you are expecting word splitting and pathname expansion to take place.